# RegExp: Not every group is captured but every matched.. (debuggex.com example)

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, re2

Test case:

```
/((adam)|(eva))+/gi.exec("adameva");

Array[4]
    0: "adameva"
    1: "eva"
    2: undefined  //(should contains captured "adam" word)
    3: "eva"
    index: 0
    input: "adameva"
    length: 4
```

As you can see there are 3 groups that can be captured

```
(...)+   - first
(adam)   - second
(eva)    - third
```

and input to test against this regex is:

```
adameva
```

as you can see in debbugex live example or above, text is matched, but..

only 1 and 3 group is captured. Why not 2? It's matched as well..

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/oXTo6r05GKJr1APX)

(when you use RE2 regular expresion engine, bug doesn't appear, if someone is intrested: https://github.com/uhop/node-re2)

Comment: It must be the ECMAScript standard that always assigns an empty value to a non-participating group. In JS, the 2nd group is re-written upon the second iteration, while in PCRE, re2 and others the group is not touched.

Comment: I was thinking similiar way. But 2nd group is participating it this case, looks like a bug.

Comment: The 2nd group is `(adam)` and when the `eva` is found the 3rd group only participates in the match.

Comment: are u sure? Because 2nd group is matched too so participates as well, I understand that we can lost 2nd group when it would be matched again, then 2nd group will capture the second match. But there is only one match for 2nd, so it should contains the match "adam" not undefined. Still looks like a bug.

Comment: It looks like every iteration of (...)+ ecma regexp engine clear inner groups, but it shouldn't.

Comment: It should since ECMAScript needs them initialized with empty values for backreferences to work they work in ECMAScript regex.

Comment: It seems to favor the first possible match, which would be the shorter one in this case. I guess `adam` is lost because the shorter `eva` match takes you past that in the string. Note the difference if you do `/((ada)|(eve))+/`

Comment: how it could interrupt backreferences? there is always only one x-nd group. Clearing inner groups sounds like wrong-design.

Comment: @squint: ((ada)|(eve))+ has same output for me

Comment: I get `[ "ada", "ada", "ada", undefined ]`

Comment: @squint: mea culpa (debuggex.com showed me wrong ?.?), but problem is still the same, now 3-nd groups isnt captured

Comment: Yeah, I always get confused about how subgroups are supposed to match when it comes to multiple matches in the string. I usually end up doing `.exec()` in a loop.

Comment: @squint good idea, but not for regex where the regex-problem-part is in the middle of complex regex. (i've made addon named-groups for RegExp and need to extract data from some of them, but I've met a problem above)

Comment: You may just need to extract that out to its own regex... but then I'm just not super knowledgeable in this area.

Comment: @squint: not a bad idea! I can get the parent group (parent for 2 and 3nd) and parse it again by even RE2 engine where everything is fine. But it is rather the last solution, anyway thanks (im not using RE2 from start because of length-limit of pattern and because of non-supported negative-lookahead)